# how to write the sql command in mysql

Tags: mysql

for example: the table named `products` there is a `product name` field in the table. i want to show some related items which matched by the knowed products's `product name`.

how to write the sql query command?

eg: if the  knowed products's `product name` is

```
True Blood Season 1 DVD
```

i want to get all the product name which begins as `True Blood Season`..

if the  knowed products's `product name` is

```
 24 Hours Season 7 DVD
```

i want to get all the product name which begins as `24 Hours Season`..

**the sql:** what's error with the sql

```
$query ="select p.products_id, pd.products_name, p.products_price
                     from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p " .
                             TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd
                     where p.products_status = 1
                     and p.products_id = pd.products_id
                     and pd.language_id = '" . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id'] . "'
                    and p.products_id <> :product_id AND MATCH('products_name') AGAINST (:products_name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Comment: [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) (e.g. table structure as `CREATE TABLE` statements) and data, along with the desired result for the sample data, would be most helpful. What's your exact criteria for determining what's related?

Comment: some parts of the given product name. thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at using MySQL [Full-Text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

This should be able to take the title of your chosen product and use it to retrieve relevant matches, eg

```
SELECT * FROM `products`
WHERE `id` <> :product_id -- don't return current product
AND MATCH(`product_name`)
AGAINST (:product_name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

This requires you to create a full-text index on your `products.product_name` column.

Comment: what's this line meaning AGAINST (:product_name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
 thank you

Comment: @runeveryday Did you read the [manual I linked to](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match)? If you're referring to `:product_name`, that's a parameter.

Comment: Phil, thank you, i have put your code in my sql command. but my IDE shows there is an error. how to correct it.thank you. i put the command on the question.

Comment: Phil,the matched product name is: $products_name how to put it in the command, thank you

Answer (score 0):

select * from products where name like 'True Blood Season%'

select * from products where name like '24 Hours Season%'

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name='title of show here';
```

It's pretty basic SQL, I'd really recommend reading up a bit before posting as this question is very entry level.  I'm more than happy to help you get started though :).

Comment: Downvotes don't help anyone (including me) unless explained.  What's the issue here?

Comment: Not tagged `PHP`. Also, this does not satisfy the question requirements

Comment: You're right, edited so that it's not PHP.  I've been fielding mostly PHP questions, oversight on my part, thanks for pointing that out :).  I assume you just mean that I'm searching for the wrong product, I had it changed so that the asker would make the connection on what goes where when changing the title, aiding future learning.